# How to use data but to hide it so as it cannot be reused

Tags: javascript, hide

I've some data that I'd like to publish just on one website, i.e. it should not be reused on other websites. The data is a set of numbers that change every day, our journalists work to get hard gather it.

Is there any way to hide, crypt, etc. the data in a way that it cannot be reused by others? But to show it in a graph in the same time?

I found the ASCII to HEX tool that could be used for (http://utenti.multimania.it/ascii2hex/). I wonder if you can suggest other ways. (Even if I have to completely change the strategy.)

Answer (score 6):

Well, if you can see it then you can reuse it.

You could use images to show graphs and have a watermark.

Answer (score 4):

You can publish a watermarked image containing the graph.

Answer (score 2):

Since the JavaScript needs to decode it in order to display the data, any encoding is easily broken by reading and reverse-engineering the JavaScript code.

If the data is only used in a graph, then may be you could generate the graph server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt javascripts, or just the data used but if someone really wants to they can decrypt it.

I would suggest fetching the data in the backend and dynamically build an image to display the graph(s). Simple image libraries such as gd+ for php can easily accomplish this.

Comment: Hi Jonas and others.

I wonder whether there was a way to make it harder for a third party to use the data in an automated way. The data will change daily and it is interesting at a given day only. Would you know of any technique that would require some work (that a third party would prefer not to do and to gather the data by themselves)? Changing the encoding key regularly seems to be an alternative but I wonder how to do it in a way that the third-party would not fetch it easily.

Lkt